# JavaScript is wrong converting big numbers from binary to hex

Tags: javascript, binary, hex, converters

I'm using a simple technique to convert binary numbers to hexadecimal.

```
parseInt('1011110000',2).toString(16) == '2f0'
parseInt('111110011111101111100111011011001',2).toString(16) == '1F3F7CED9'
```

With larger binary numbers, I'm encountering a problem:

```
parseInt('11000011010011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100',2).toString(16);
```

Returns `c34cccccccccd0` instead of correct value `c34cccccccccc`.

Minus four bits solve the problem:

```
parseInt('1100001101001100110011001100110011001100110011001100',2).toString(16);
```

Returns `c34cccccccccc`.

Why does this happen? How can I avoid this problem and convert large binary numbers into hexadecimal numbers?

Comment: The number's too big, JS can't handle it, sorry.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin